# CICD Pipeline Deployment stage unable to come out after successful deployment

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

Background : Spring boot application deployment using cicd pipeline declarative script

Issue :

The spring boot application jar file is able to launch successfully. After some time we can access application health info also from browser but the build job is unable to exit from deployment stage. It is spinning at this stage continuously.

Action Taken: even we have added `timeout=120000` in launch command but no change in behaviour.

Help : please help us how can we make clean exit after deployment stage from jenkin cicd declarative pipeline.

We are ssh'ing and executing our launch command. The code is like:

```
sshagent([sshAgent]) { sh "scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -v *.jar sudouser@${server}:/opt/project/tmp/application-demo.jar" sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null sudouser@${server} nohup '/opt/java/hotspot/8/64_bit/jdk1.8.0_141/bin/java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=$profile -Dhttpport=8890 - /opt/project/tmp/application-demo.jar ' timeout=120000" }
```

I need to come out (clean exit) from jenkins build after deployment stage is successful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the *'&'* to the start process in backgroud
Example:

```
nohup '/opt/java/hotspot/8/64_bit/jdk1.8.0_141/bin/java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active = $ profile -Dhttpport = 8890 - /opt/project/tmp/application-demo.jar &
```

You can also put an *'if'* condition for when the log appears 'started in' to exit execution.
Example:

```
status(){
  timeout=$1
  process=$2
  log=$3
  string=$4
  if (timeout ${timeout} tail -f  ${log} &) | grep "${string}" ; then
    echo "${process} started with success."
  else
    echo "${process} startup failed." 1>&2
    exit 1
  fi
}

start_app(){
   java -jar -dspring.profiles.active=$profile -dhttpport=8890 - /opt/project/tmp/application-demo.jar >> /tmp/log.log 2>&1 &
   status "60" "application-demo" "/tmp/log.log" "started"
}
```

Comment: we have tried  appending '&' in launch command but there is no change in behavior..its spinning after deployment and not exit from pipeline script.

Comment: Please, try ` 2>&1 &`